# DB2 - select multiple key values for common primary key

Tags: db2

I have following data

### ID KEY Value

1  K1   1

---

1  K2   2

---

2  K1   3

---

2  K2   4

---

3  K1   5

---

3  K2   6

I need to do a select from above table data in DB2 to display like following  -

### ID Key1 Value Key2 Value

1   K1    1    K2    2

---

2   K1    3    K2    4

---

3   K1    5    K2    6

Comment: Please describe your logic and do not make us guess. Are there always only two keys (K1 and K2) etc...

Comment: Yes there are only 2 keys K1 and K2, but values can be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join your source table with itself.

One possible solution would be:

```
select t1.ID, t1.KEY as KEY1, t1.value, t2KEY as KEY2, t2.value
  from <tabname> t1,
       <tabname> t2
 where t1.ID = t2.ID 
   and t1.KEY='K1'
   and t2.KEY='K2'
```

Comment: ...Please, always explicitly qualify your joins, don't use the implicit syntax.  For one thing, it makes it much clearer what some relationships are.